# Event listener don't detect the finish of a video

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html 5 player and I am trying to detect when the video finishes.I tried to detect it with JQUERY and javascript so far no luck.

```
<video id="myVideo"></video>

$("#myVideo").bind("ended", function () {
    alert('Video ended!');
});

var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.src = "Content/Test.mp4";
vid.play();

vid.addEventListener('ended', videoFinish, false);

function videoFinish() {
    alert('Video ended!');
}
```

Comment: I think you'd have to have a video ... not just a video tag maybe? how does a video tag with no media "end"? also, your javascript needs to be in a `<script>` tag

Comment: i think you must specify the src for the video you have created or which you're linking to.

Comment: your code looks correct but on a side not never create variables without var, let or const in front of them (do `var vid =...`). Also `bind` was deprecated 5 years ago in favour of `.on`, although your native version should be doing the same thing

Comment: The var is there.I missed it when I was copying the code. I am assigning the video from the controller.

Comment: As an experiment try statically putting in the video attributes (in the html) see if that makes any difference compared with programatically doing it

Comment: you can check if any event attaches propperly. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#geteventlistenersobject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine on the JavaScript part, but if you prefer to use jQuery, you should dereference any jQuery objects you intend to use with JavaScript API for video methods and properties. Details are commented in Snippet.

BTW, [`.bind()` jQuery method is deprecated, the `.on()` method is it's replacement.](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#entry-longdesc)

**SNIPPET**

```js
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
|| Plain JavaScript 
*/
// Creating <video>
var vid1 = document.createElement("video");

/* Assigning:
|| #id
|| src
|| controls
*/
vid1.id = 'vid1';
vid1.src = 'http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/023642.mp4';
vid1.controls = true;

// Add node to DOM
document.body.appendChild(vid1);

// Register #vid1 to ended event to call videoFinish()
vid1.addEventListener('ended', videoFinish, false);

/*~~~~~~~
|| jQuery
*/
// Append this jQuery object to the DOM
$('<video id="vid2" src="http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/023642.mp4" controls></video>').appendTo('body');

/* Dereference a jQuery object in order to use a 
|| method from a JavaScript API like HTML5 Video by
|| using bracket notation.
*/
var vid2 = $('#vid2')[0];

/* Now vid2 is a plain JavaScript object like vid1
|| Now it can easily use video methods and properties
*/
vid2.addEventListener('ended', videoFinish, false);

function videoFinish(e) {
  alert(e.target.id + ' has ended!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#myVideo').on('ended',function(){
          alert('Video ended!');
}
```

Or

```
<video src="video/endscene.mp4" id="myVideo" controls onended="videoEnded()">
```

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference compared to what is already there

Comment: I remember using the second one a long time ago and it worked. I agree that this is just another way of doing the same thing as "asker" did, however it worked for me that way. Furthermore I gave proper way to put video control in html. I think the problem is here.

Comment: Interesting, maybe it fixes the issue I'm guessing is happening

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you're programmatically adding the src or playing the video (but only a guess as you didn't reply to my question). Try adding the event after the video has loaded:

```
function onVideoLoaded(e) {
  console.log('onVideoLoaded', e.target === vid);
  vid.addEventListener('ended', onVideoEnded);
}

function onVideoEnded() {
  console.log('onVideoEnded');
}

vid.addEventListener('loadstart', onVideoLoaded);
```